# What can be the reason for a three phase fused socket to always blow the same fuse?

Tags: three-phase, fuses

I am supplying a 30 kW load through a 3 phase socket. The socket is fused and the same fuse (same phase) is always blowing after a few hours of usage.

What are the possible reasons for a single line fuse blown in a 3 phase system?

EDIT: load is a DC power supply

Comment: Have you checked the other two fuses? Have you replaced all with the same fuse and retested? You used to be really good at accepting answers in the early days. What happened?

Comment: I'd measure the phase currents with a quality AC clamp meter. Could be uneven load, or intermittent short on that leg.

Comment: If the correct type of fuse is used and all 3 have the same fuse, the issue is likely in the equipment you connected to it.  As for the consistent timing, that could be a function of the fuse getting slowly worn out from the problem or something in the equipment heating up.  If you can, check equipment for faulty/degraded insulation.

Comment: What is the load?  Is it a balanced load, if it is, is it truly balanced or mostly balanced?  Did it function properly for some known period of time and then start blowing fuses, or is this the initial install?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, other 2 fuses checked. Replaced all fuses and retested. I am not sure I get your last question.. could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @mickkk [reason why free help is given](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: He means that you have asked about 60 questions on the site but only accepted answers to ten of them. You used to take the trouble to accept answers but seem to have stopped. If you are not getting good answers to that many questions then it suggests that the questions are poor or not clear. If you are getting good answer then you should acknowledge the work put in by others at no cost to you. This is something you can fix.

Comment: @Transistor and the reason is simple. I mostly stopped using the website and forgot to accept answers where appropriate. I am going through some of my old questions at the moment.

Comment: @mickkk how balanced is the incoming three phase supply. In other words, if one phase is a little hot compared to the other two, it could account for an excessive current draw. Maybe you can measure the current on each phase?

Answer (score 5):

To be sure if the problem comes from the load, I should shift the phases of wires. That is, if existing wiring connection is Fuse1-Wire1,Fuse2-Wire2, Fuse3-Wire3, then change to Fuse1-Wire2,Fuse2-Wire3, Fuse3-Wire1. Rotation will keep the same, and check again. If same fuse is blowing, could be an issue in fuse holder (bad contact is heating the fuse). If the fuse blown is another one, the fault is in the load, may be a ground fault or unbalanced current.

Comment: If the load is a 3-phase motor, the motor rotation will change if you swap phases.

Comment: "the motor rotation will change if you swap phases."  If you swap any two phases, yes. It won't if you rotate all the phases one step as @Bravale suggested.